# How do I invite a user to talk in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I am concerned with a poster's question on feeding problems and want them to feel supported even if the question is put on hold. Is this okay from the community 'rules' point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enough reputation to create a chat about any topic you like, but remember it will not be private.

Just go into chat from the top menu bar and you will see options for doing this.

Comment: thanks, not worried about private, just want a non answer format until I understand.

Comment: You can also magic link to the site's main chat by typing `[chat]` in the comments, so they don't have to search for it. It'll look like this when it works: [chat]

Answer (score 0):

You can invite a user directly to chat (i.e. without having to create the room first then post a comment with the link), if they got 20 reputation across Stack Exchange. (i.e. sum of their reputation in all sites.)

To do that follow those steps:

1. Go to [Stack Exchange chat users page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users).
2. In the top right text box, type the display name of the desired user, e.g.

   > [image]
3. Click the name to reach the user's chat profile.
4. Click the "start a new room with this user" button:

   > [image]

A new room will be created (**note: no confirmation dialog**) and the other user will get inbox notification with a link to the room. No comments, no noise.

Comment: How cool is that! Thanks! I think I am getting to know stuff and then learn something else. Maybe now I'm halfway there! ;) Is my 'inbox' the red square that notifies me that someone has commented? And ignore this user, how does that work? I'll assume we can't ignore mods and that an ignored user can still vote on your questions or answers? Can an ignored user see your posts even if you can't see theirs? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: @WillowRex lol, all good... Yes inbox is the red square that lits up when you get new comments (or answers, like this one :)), as for Ignore it applies only for chat and means you will not see messages posted by this user **in chat**, it does not affect the ordinary sites and the questions or answers of that user.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, I have learned something today. (now I can go play!) ;)

Comment: @WillowRex hey what you play? ;)

Comment: House ;) -- seriously, I am writing a novel (sci-fi), I'm retired. I also enjoy the Sims and used to play WOW, but it got too intense.

Comment: @WillowRex House game?? Never heard of it... Well glad you enjoy your time, good luck with the novel! :)

Comment: house -- little girls play 'house'. Perhaps that is just a Canadian thing from the 50s, but to me it means I am home with my husband and enjoying the day. Then it meant pretending to be a mum and pretending to have a husband.

Comment: @WillowRex lol... Lost you... Well you can always explain to me better in chat... ;-)